# Looking for Kris Kringle book

Tags: story-identification, books, santa-claus

I'm looking for a Christmas-themed (but not religious) book whose title at least partially contains "Kris Kringle."

As it was described to me, pages (at least of one edition) were gold-edged.

Apparently a young boy rehabilitates a reindeer inside a cave and is rewarded by Santa (Kris Kringle) with the opportunity to accompany him on Christmas Eve.

Comment: How is this on-topic? Since Santa is real, this is basically a drama story

Comment: Good point; can someone point me towards biographies SE?

Comment: How does he rehabilitate the reindeer? Does he get it free of alcoholism?

Comment: Physically I think (injured leg?). Although Rudolph's red nose does arouse suspicion.

Comment: We admitted that we were powerless over reindeer games - that our red noses had become unmanageable.